# Get total count as well as group count in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, database, count

[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2963d3/9)

I'm curious to see if there's other option to get the total count as well as group count in one query.

Is using a sub-query the go-to way of getting this result:

```
TOTAL   OPTIONS OPTION_COUNT
4       A       3
4       B       1
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE poll
    (`poll_id` int,`user_id` int,`options` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO poll
    (`poll_id`,`user_id`,`options`)
VALUES
    (1,1,'A'),
    (2,2,'A'),
    (3,3,'B'),
    (4,4,'A')
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*) AS total FROM poll)AS total
,options,option_count
FROM 
(
  SELECT options,Count(options) AS option_count
  FROM poll
  GROUP BY options
)p
GROUP BY options
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it using `group by rollup`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
SELECT options,Count(options) AS option_count
FROM poll
GROUP BY options
WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't be possible without sub query but one can write in a different and much simpler way like:

select options,Count(options), (SELECT Count(*) FROM poll) from poll GROUP BY options;